# Java if- else strings .contains not working error

Tags: java, android, string, firebase, if-statement

If I put `entity.about = "phone"` and `test = "phone"` then the search list is updated but if I put `entity.about = "this is phone"` and `test = "phone"` then the search list is not updated.

```
public void onSearchConfirmed(final CharSequence text) {
    productsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("products");
    searchList.clear();
    final String test = text.toString();
    productsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ProductEntity entity = postSnapshot.getValue(ProductEntity.class);
                if(entity.about.contains(test) || entity.vendor_address.contains(test)) {
                    searchList.add(entity) ;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post a reproducible example of your problem?  What you are describing should not be happening.

Comment: Try to print entity.about and test value before if condition and check actual value before if executed.

Comment: I found it. It was because I didnt add .tolowercase before searching.

Comment: @RahulMishra post as answer & accept yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong not considering the fact that contains function in String class is actually case sensitive. This is what I needed to do:

```
final String test = text.toString().toLowerCase() ;
    productsRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                ProductEntity entity = postSnapshot.getValue(ProductEntity.class);
                if(entity.about.toLowerCase().contains(test) || entity.vendor_address.toLowerCase().contains(test)) {
                    searchList.add(entity) ;
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace code:`entity.about.contains(test)` with `entity.about.toLowerCase.contains(test)`